# Sylow subgroups of $D_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I am working on finding all $2$- and $3$-Sylow subgroups of $D_{6}$. $$D_6=\langle x,y:x^6=y^2=1,xy=yx^{-1}\rangle$$ 
The answer I got is:

$2$-Sylow : $$\{1, x^3, y, yx^3\}\\\{1, x^3, yx, yx^4\}\\ \{1, x^3, yx^2, yx^5\}$$

$3$-Sylow : $$\{1, x^2, x^4\}$$

Is the answer right and exhaustive? Thanks.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Yes, as you can see it also agrees with the second and third Sylow theorems.